# How to print a line on Terminal Using Clang Libtooling?

Tags: c++, clang, libtooling

I am relatively new to CLang and Libtooling. I want to display a Line from the source code on the terminal. I have a *VisitFunctionDecl(FunctionDecl *func)* in the *RecursiveASTVisitor*. For every function I get the *SourceRange* and from that the *SourceLocation*. But I dont understand how to display that. I has something to do

Comment: Can't you use [`SourceLocation::print`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1SourceLocation.html#ae4ea241af69a871313e928909db6633d) or [`SourceLocation::printToString`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1SourceLocation.html#a700ac4324e055d2d96e9764f4d507103)?

Comment: I need SourceManager and I dont know how to access/declare that.

Comment: Don't you have an [`ASTContext`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1ASTContext.html) pointer? It can give you a `SourceManager` reference. Or give you a [`FullSourceLoc`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1FullSourceLoc.html) instance which you can use directly to get the source line (if I read the reference correctly). Maybe you should read e.g. [this `RecursiveASTVisitor` tutorial](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/RAVFrontendAction.html)?'

Comment: Thank you very much. As you said I used the ASTContext to get the FllSourceLoc and using that I got what I was lookinf for.

Answer (score 0):

You need the FullSourceLoc:

```
    FullSourceLoc functionDeclFullLocation = Context->getFullLoc(func.getLocStart());
    if (functionDeclFullLocation.isValid())
        llvm::outs() << "Found FunctionDecl at "
        << functionDeclFullLocation.getManager().getFilename(functionDeclFullLocation) << ":"
        << functionDeclFullLocation.getSpellingLineNumber() << ":"
        << functionDeclFullLocation.getSpellingColumnNumber() << "\n";
```